# What reposiroty type should I check in Artifactory OSS to proxy MavenCentral and JCenter?

Tags: artifactory

I grabbed Artifactory OSS, change storage location and run application.

Under http://localhost:.../... I was asked for repository type.

My goal is to proxy in-house repositories to make possible offline/out-of-office development and I use in `build.gradle`:

```
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
```

Artifactory OSS provides:

- Generic
- Gradle
- Ivy
- Maven

variants. What should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `Maven` is the right choice.
Also, no need to proxy both [jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) and maven central, see the following:
[Why should I use jcenter over maven central](https://www.jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-should-i-use-jcenter-over-maven-central/)

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [[image]bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray) and [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `Maven` repository type is appropriate.

Predefined for proxing `jcenter` repository is Maven type.